# Someone has managed to get the balance of an ERC20 Token with Web3.js@1.0.0?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, blockchain, web3js

This code worked for version 0.20.6, but for the new version it doesn't work anymore. I've been reading the documentation and testing the examples, but I haven't gotten it to work.
Here is the code that worked below.

```
let contract = web3.eth.contract(ABI).at(tokenAddress);
  contract.balanceOf(walletAddress, (error, balance) => {
    contract.decimals((error, decimals) => {
      balance = balance.div(10 ** decimals);
      console.log(balance.toString());
    });
  });
```

Please let me know some way to deal with this.

Answer (score 3):

In web3@1.0 you have to use `myContract.methods.myMethod()` and can use `.then` for the response. Callback can also be used.

And for the contract instance `new web3.eth.Contract(jsonInterface, address, options)`

or can add address later to the instance `myContract.address = '0x1234FFDD...';`

```
let contract = web3.eth.contract(ABI, tokenAddress);
  contract.methods.balanceOf(walletAddress).call((error, balance) => {
    contract.methods.decimals().call((error, decimals) => {
      balance = balance.div(10 ** decimals);
      console.log(balance.toString());
    });
  });
```